# Identify mouseclick first and if not trigger for mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseclick-event

I have two functionalities: `mouseover` and `mouseclick`. I had written corresponding functionalities in corresponding events. However the problem is that each time, the `mouseover` is triggered even if I intended to `mouseclick`.

Is there any way to identify the `mouseclick` first and if not, trigger for `mouseover` event?

```
$('.test').mouseover(function (event) {
    // ...
}

$('.test').mouseclick(function (event) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. `mouseover` always fires before a click as the mouse has to be over the element to be able to click it.

Comment: You first mouseover, then you click!

Comment: Can have some `flag` to check and control the events ?

Comment: At hover, i am popping up `qtip` tooltip info and hiding when mose left, and at mouse click, i am making the popup fixed to window.

Answer (score 0):

You can not click without mouseover. In case of links or buttons, you can use the "tab" key and reach there and click that, but in general using mouse it's impossible to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using right approach to do this things, But still you can use a solution to achieve your requirement.

```
var myVar;
$('.test').mouseenter(function (event) {
     myVar = setTimeout(function(){ 
       console.info('over')
     }, 2000);         
})

$('.test').click(function (event) {
     clearTimeout(myVar);    
    console.info('click')
})
```

In this code when you'll hover the element it will set the code to run after 2 seconds. But if you click the element before 2 seconds, it will clear the timeout and will not run code in settimeout function. It will be good to use **mouseenter** in place of **mouseover** in this case.
Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the click event first, however, using a flag.
Try running the code snippet given below and try clicking on the gray area:

```js
$clicked = false;

$('.test').on("click", function (event) {
    $('.msg').append("<div>click</div>").delay(3000).find("div:last").fadeOut(200, function(){$(this).remove();});
    $clicked = !$clicked;
    if($clicked)
      $(this).mouseover();
});

$('.test').on("mouseover", function (event) {
    if($clicked){
        $('.msg').append("<div>mouseover</div>").delay(10000).find("div:last").fadeOut(500, function(){$(this).remove();});
    }
    else $(this).html('');
});

$('.test').on("mousemove", function (event) {
    if($clicked){
        $(this).html("mousemove: pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY);
    }
    else $(this).html('');
});
```

```css
.test {
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #efefef;
  }
.msg {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  
</div>
<div class="msg"></div>
```